# How to change the colour of each tickMark in SeekBar

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to change the colour of each specific *tickMark*.

Example: 1st Tick - Yellow, 2nd Tick - Red, 3rd Tick - White and so on...

Here is my SeekBar:

```
 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/tareaSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:max="4"
        android:progress="1"
        android:thumbTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorSecondary"
        android:tickMark="@drawable/tick_mark"

        />
```

And the TickMark drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="4dp"
          android:height="4dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution changing the first tick:

```
class FirstTickSeekBar @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatSeekBar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private val firstTickId: Int
    private val otherTicksId: Int

    init {
        val typedArray = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FirstTickSeekBar, 0, 0)
        firstTickId = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.FirstTickSeekBar_firstTick, 0)
        otherTicksId = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.FirstTickSeekBar_otherTicks, 0)
        typedArray.recycle()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.let {
            drawTickMarks(canvas)
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }

    private fun drawTickMarks(canvas: Canvas) {
        val firstTickMark = resources.getDrawable(firstTickId, null)
        val tickMark = resources.getDrawable(otherTicksId, null)
        val count = max

        if (count > 1) {
            val w = tickMark.intrinsicWidth
            val h = tickMark.intrinsicHeight
            val halfW = if (w >= 0) w / 2 else 1
            val halfH = if (h >= 0) h / 2 else 1
            tickMark.setBounds(-halfW, -halfH, halfW, halfH)
            firstTickMark.setBounds(-halfW, -halfH, halfW, halfH)

            val spacing = (width - paddingLeft - paddingRight) / count.toFloat()
            val saveCount = canvas.save()
            canvas.translate(paddingLeft.toFloat(), (height / 2).toFloat())

            for (i in 0..count) {
                if (i == 0) firstTickMark.draw(canvas) else tickMark.draw(canvas)
                canvas.translate(spacing, 0f)
            }

            canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount)
        }
    }
}
```

attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="FirstTickSeekBar">
    <attr name="firstTick"/>
    <attr name="otherTicks"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

usage:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <com.mypackage.FirstTickSeekBar
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_bigger"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_bigger"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_seekbar"
            android:max="4"
            android:progress="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@color/transparent"
            app:tickMark="@color/transparent"
            app:firstTick="@drawable/bg_seekbar_tick_first"
            app:otherTicks="@drawable/bg_seekbar_tick_mark"
            android:thumb="@drawable/bg_seekbar_thumb"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thank you! So, how can we adjust the heights of the ones other than the active thumb? Because the active ones are big, the others are small.